# how to go back to a div which was active in previous page onclicking back link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am using a toggling of divs when clicking on links . Each div is having their own form which gets submitted to new page and there i use go back link to go to previous page . But it does not open that particular div which was active on form submitting time. Here's the code i am using

```
<style>
.selected{
     color:red;
}
</style>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pro" target="1">
            link2 
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pro" target="2">
            link 1
</a>
<div  id='div1' class="itargetDiv" >
   <form method="post" action="a.php">
        <input type="text" name="t1">
        <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="s1">
   </form>
</div>
<div  id='div2' class="itargetDiv" style="display:none;">
     <form method="post" action="a.php">
         <input type="text" name="t3">
         <input type="text" name="t4">
         <input type="text" name="t5">
         <input type="text" name="t6"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="s2">
     </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".pro").click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
            var pullNumber = $(this).attr("target");       
           $("#div"+pullNumber).show(500).siblings(".itargetDiv").hide(500);    
       });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: save the state of the page and load it after you come back

Comment: @madalinivascu By `save the state` he mean to save it in `cookie` (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or `localStorage` (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Guess you need to use session or localStorage. I dont think its a best solution but this will work...

In your jquery add this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var a = localStorage.getItem("active_section");

        if(a=='1')
           $("#div"+a).show(500).siblings(".itargetDiv").hide(500);
        else if(a=='2')
           $("#div"+a).show(500).siblings(".itargetDiv").hide(500);
        else
           $("#div1").show(500).siblings(".itargetDiv").hide(500);//Default section u want to show

        $(".pro").click(function(){

           $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
           var pullNumber = $(this).attr("target");    
           localStorage.setItem("active_section",pullNumber);   //Add this line
           $("#div"+pullNumber).show(500).siblings(".itargetDiv").hide(500);    
       });
    });
```

Comment: no its not working still showing 1st div only @Amin Kodaganur

Comment: now i copied whole code of yours and its showing both of them even if i refresh the page

Comment: Edited the ans ... I guess we need to have if condition like this  [ if(a=='1') ]

Comment: no i have added an alert for "a" and its showing 2 . Even on hardset address bar.??

Comment: you need to apply some logic here... step1: In starting page before coming to this page you need to clear a localStorage. step2: first time it this page will show default section and based on the selection it will set local storage and move to next page. step3: once you reached 3rd page wen click back the localstorage is already set and it will display the section based on condition...

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific  `classes` to divs so when you click back you will be able to know which divs where clicked